# Печать и отправка на почту документа сформированного в скрипте

Tags: php, javascript, docx

Есть ли возможность отправить на печать и отправить на почту документ сформированный с помощью php или js? Для js использую jszip.

Если есть такая возможность, подскажите куда плыть..

Comment: Есть, для печати я бы посоветовал использовать JS и функции `print`, а для отправки на почту можно PHP

Comment: В интернетах я не нашел, как передать документ сформированный в php через ajax и отправить его на печать. если можете как-то подсказать, буду весьма признателен)

Comment: Вам нужно открыть документ в новой вкладке и вызвать печать документа window.print() как писал @erm чуть выше. 
Тут всё зависит от того, какой формат документа вы пытаетесь распечатать и с помощью чего его отрендерить на странице!